# Fast remote access to Mac OS X virtual machine from Linux

Tags: linux, mac, virtual-machine, vnc, nx

I have installed Mac OS X El Capitan to a KVM/Qemu virtual machine on Gentoo.
Native spice/vnc is totally unusable and slow. Native Mac OS X VNC server and linux's vncviewer is also unusable and slow, even moving windows or anything else.

I need some fast access to my local mac virtual machine, so I can feel like a native. I had some success with Nomachine NX, but now we need to use only open source software on linux side.

I tried to connect opennx with Nomachine NX server on Mac OS and failed.

Is there any other ways accessing mac desktop fastly?

Comment: As you're running an unlicensed OS on an unsupported platform, you may be on your own.

Comment: This is just technical details. The question is about fast access a mac desktop from linux via remote software.

Comment: Well, the 'technical details' are what's preventing anyone answering - you're floating an unlicensed OS on top of unsupported hardware - the connectivity between the two is possibly unique to you.

Comment: Well, I am doing it on Apple hardware, and license allows it. Vmware officially support it including Sierra right after it release. https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/   I just don't entirely like Mac OS X and prefer Gentoo as main OS

Comment: Well, that's 5 comments we could have saved if you'd mentioned that in your question:/